# Why shuffling the data like this leads to a poor accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am reading the book "Hands-On Machine Learning" and I have a problem with exercise 9 of chapter 13, the exercise is as follows:

> **a.** Load the Fashion MNIST dataset (introduced in Chapter 10); split it into a training set,
> a validation set, and a test set; shuffle the training set; and save each dataset to multiple
> TFRecord files. Each record should be a serialized Example protobuf with two features: the
> serialized image (use tf.io.serialize_tensor() to serialize each image), and the label.
>
> **b.** Then use tf.data to create an efficient dataset for each set. Finally, use a Keras
> model to train these datasets, including a preprocessing layer to standardize each input feature.

You can find the exercise with the solution at the end of this notebook: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/13_loading_and_preprocessing_data.ipynb

I loaded the data like this:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(X_full_train, y_full_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_valid = X_full_train[:55000], X_full_train[55000:]
y_train, y_valid = y_full_train[:55000], y_full_train[55000:]

# Why shuffling the data like this leads to a very poor accuracy?
X_train = shuffle(X_train) 

X_train = X_train.reshape(55000, 784)
X_valid = X_valid.reshape(5000, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)

train_data = np.c_[X_train, y_train]
valid_data = np.c_[X_valid, y_valid]
test_data = np.c_[X_test, y_test]

def save_to_multiple_tfrecord_files(data, name_prefix, n_parts):
    # this function saves a dataset to multiple TFRecord files using the Example 
    # protobuf and returns the file paths (please use the link below to see the full code)
```

After that, I loaded the data using this function:

```
def tfrecord_reader_mnist(filepaths, ..., batch_size=32):
    # ...
    # load the data, preprocess it, and shuffle it (use the link below for the full code)
    # ...
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.prefetch(1)
```

After that, I standardized the data using a `Standradization` and create the model:

```
class Standardization(keras.layers.Layer):
    def adapt(self, data_sample):
        self.means_ = np.mean(data_sample, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        self.stds_ = np.std(data_sample, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    def call(self, inputs):
        return (inputs - self.means_) / (self.stds_ + keras.backend.epsilon())

# ...

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    standardization,
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_set, epochs=5, validation_data=valid_set,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])
```

When the fit method is executed I had this accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/5
1719/1719 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 600.4416 - accuracy: 0.1032 - val_loss: 148.7675 - val_accuracy: 0.1236
# ...
Epoch 5/5
1719/1719 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 187.1646 - accuracy: 0.1338 - val_loss: 58.7837 - val_accuracy: 0.1564
```

If I just comment the line where I shuffle the data (this: `X_train = shuffle(X_train)` ), I get this accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/5
1719/1719 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4473 - accuracy: 0.8424 - val_loss: 0.3331 - val_accuracy: 0.8796
# ...
Epoch 5/5
1719/1719 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2464 - accuracy: 0.9089 - val_loss: 0.2185 - val_accuracy: 0.9179
```

The author book used the `shuffle` function from TensorFlow (I used that of sklearn).

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

If you want to test my code please follow use this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1T6OJqwEeCIUJyAWwmIGoSaF86gUK9wPL?usp=sharing

I also copied the author's solution from the book into a notebook so you can test it straight away.: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z5a8SJg0tzeV5s7MTOY_uU-dCxSC8tjv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are shuffling only the input data (`X_train`) without applying the same shuffling to the corresponding labels `y_train`. You should shuffle both together:

```py
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: x) I see! I posted this whole post for such a stupid mistake. thank you though.

Comment: It happens. We've all been there :)